# AWS Elastic Beanstalk URL points to incorrect IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Recently somebody manually deleted all Elastic Load Balancers on a AWS account I am working with. All the Load balancers had been provisioned from Elastic Beanstalk configs.

I rebuilt all the Elastic Beanstalk instances from previous configs to restore the deleted load balancers. The various applications are now running correctly apart from 2 which are failing to send traffic to each other. I will call them App A and App B.

App A is sending traffic to App B using its elastic beanstalk URL, however the messages are failing to send. If I SSH into App A, I can manually send JSON messages to App B using CURL and the EC2 private IP. When I ping the EB URL from App B, it shows me a IP to do not recognise and which is not allocated to any EC2 instances running on the account.

App B is in a private subnet with a network load balancer.

How can I get the Elastic Beanstalk URL to point at the correct IP.

I have recently inherited this environment and did not configure the original setup. So perhaps I am missing a step or aspect of how AWS Elastic Bean stalk is intended to work in this regard.

Additionally I am certain this is not a programmatic error ( the code has not changed since the instances where rebuild ) or a firewall setting as I am manually able to send traffic and get a response with a curl script.

Its is the beanstalk URL which appears to be incorrect